# Regex - Exclude a string starting with multiples occurrency

Tags: regex

Using phpstorm regexp search (only for your info)  i need to search any string in a files that contain

```
\\
```

and not start previusly with

```
http:
https:
http:\
https:\
[
]
```

I try with something like this with a no complete success...

```
^(?!http:\\*|http:\\\\*|\[\\\\*)\\
```

for example i need to find only \ like some string Es.

```
$upload_dir="\\foo\\bar";
```

and avoid something like

```
http:\\www.google.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the repeated characters *outside* the lookahead, so that they get consumed properly (otherwise, after the end of the lookahead, the engine will still have only matched the position at the very beginning of the string).

Note that if `http:` is disallowed, then a rule for that will automatically also disallow `http:\` (and the same for https), so there's no need to separate those out - just `https?:` will suffice.

```
^(?!https?:|[[\]]).*\\\\
```

https://regex101.com/r/RwYB2P/1

Comment: thank u but on phpstom not work the search...i need to find only \\ like some string 
Es.
    $upload_dir="\\foo\\bar";
and avoid something like
    http:\\www.google.it
Understand?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "not work"? What gets matched that shouldn't be, or what doesn't get matched that should be? Those two strings you posted seem to be matched and excluded as desired (if you want the entire line, then add on a `.*` to the end)

Comment: I don't know if PHPStorm uses the `m` flag by default - if it doesn't, then `^` will only match the beginning of the string, not the beginning of a line. Try prepending the pattern with `(?m)`, eg ``(?m)^(?!https?:|[[\]]).*\\\\``

Comment: with this
^(?!https?:|\[[\]]).*\\\\
some news....escaping the [ according php documentation that says here...
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/tutorial-finding-and-replacing-text-using-regular-expressions.html
seems to work all execept http:\\\
any solution?
see last screen
https://imgur.com/a/A9sA6Ej
THANK U

Comment: Only a *very few* characters need to be escaped inside a character set, `[` isn't one of them, though you do need to escape `]` (usually)

Comment: The `^` anchors to the beginning of a line - if the `http` is not at the beginning of the line, the line won't be excluded. If you want to check that the line doesn't contain `https?:` *anywhere*, then put `.*` at the beginning of the lookahead, eg https://regex101.com/r/RwYB2P/2